# Как собрать war файл?

Tags: eclipse, maven, opensource

Есть [open source project](https://github.com/jtalks-org/jcommune). Закинул в Эклипс, пытаюсь собрать, не выходит. В pom файле подсвечивается ошибка в строке 330:

```
Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.codehaus.gmavenplus:gmavenplus-plugin:1.2:testCompile (execution: default, phase: test-compile)
```

В интернете находил информацию, что лучшее решение это использовать IDE IntelliJ IDEA, т.к код писался на ней. Но как это приспособить к Eclipse?
Код pom'a ниже:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <artifactId>jcommune-view</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.jtalks.jcommune</groupId>
    <version>3.4-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>jcommune-web-view</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>${project.artifactId}</name>
<url>www.jtalks.org</url>
<description>
This module contains web resources (images, js, html, jsp, etc) and other
web related resources, like web.xml.
```

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>atg.taglib.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-taglib</artifactId>
        <version>0.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.cj.trim</groupId>
        <artifactId>trim-filter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>opensymphony</groupId>
        <artifactId>sitemesh</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcommune-web-controller</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcommune-service</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time-jsptags</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wro4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <targetGroups>main,pm,cr,post,user,plugin,topic,topicDraft,postDraft</targetGroups>
                <minimize>true</minimize>
                <destinationFolder>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/resources/wro</destinationFolder>
                <cssDestinationFolder>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/resources/wro</cssDestinationFolder>
                <jsDestinationFolder>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/resources/wro</jsDestinationFolder>
                <contextFolder>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/</contextFolder>
                <wroFile>${basedir}/wro.xml</wroFile>
                <wroManagerFactory>
                    ro.isdc.wro.extensions.manager.standalone.GoogleStandaloneManagerFactory
                </wroManagerFactory>
                <ignoreMissingResources>false</ignoreMissingResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <wait>true</wait>
                <container>
                    <containerId>tomcat6x</containerId>
                    <type>installed</type>
                    <home>${env.CATALINA_HOME}</home>
                </container>
                <configuration>
                    <type>existing</type>
                    <home>${env.CATALINA_HOME}</home>
                </configuration>
                <deployer>
                    <type>installed</type>
                    <deployables>
                        <deployable>
                            <groupId>org.jtalks.jcommune</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jcommune-web-view</artifactId>
                            <type>war</type>
                        </deployable>
                    </deployables>
                </deployer>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <!--Substitutes version number into a source code to show it on the page -->
            <configuration>
                <!--useCache=true needed for maven replacer plugin to access resources, 
                    as well as prepare-package phase and goal exploded in execution -->
                <useCache>true</useCache>
                <packagingExcludes>
                    resources/css/app/**,resources/css/lib/**,resources/javascript/**,
                    <!-- Ignore jsp-classes compiled by jspc -->
                    WEB-INF/classes/jsp/**
                </packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>war-pack</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exploded</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                            <nonFilteredFileExtension>gif</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                            <nonFilteredFileExtension>ico</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                            <nonFilteredFileExtension>jpg</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                            <nonFilteredFileExtension>png</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                        </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                        <webResources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </webResources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <!--Replacer plugin allows us to reduce the size of jsp pages by about 
                30% -->
            <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>replace</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <basedir>${project.build.directory}</basedir>
                <includes>
                    <!--Scan all jsp and tag files for get rid of spaces -->
                    <include>${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/**/*.jsp</include>
                    <include>${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/**/*.tag</include>
                </includes>
                <regexFlags>
                    <regexFlag>MULTILINE</regexFlag>
                </regexFlags>
                <unescape>true</unescape>
                <replacements>
                    <!--Remove all new line characters(Windows and Unix) -->
                    <replacement>
                        <token>\r\n|\n</token>
                        <value />
                    </replacement>
                    <replacement>
                        <!--Removes spaces, tabs and line breaks after " or ' -->
                        <token>("|')(\s{2,})(.)</token>
                        <value>$1 $3</value>
                    </replacement>
                    <replacement>
                        <!--Removes spaces, tabs and line breaks after '>' -->
                        <token>(&gt;)(\s+)</token>
                        <value>&gt;</value>
                    </replacement>
                    <replacement>
                        <!--Removes spaces, tabs and line breaks before '<' -->
                        <token>(\s+)(&lt;)</token>
                        <value>&lt;</value>
                    </replacement>
                </replacements>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <!-- Compile JSP to check for errors. Executes during process-classes 
                phase. Use jspc:compile to execute plugin directly. See http://jira.jtalks.org/browse/JC-1641 -->
            <groupId>org.jasig.mojo.jspc</groupId>
            <artifactId>jspc-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <!-- Compiled jsp shouldn't be added to the war, but this option doesn't 
                    work: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MJSPC-45 -->
                <includeInProject>false</includeInProject>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jasig.mojo.jspc</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jspc-compiler-tomcat6</artifactId>
                    <version>2.0.0</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testSources>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*.groovy</include>
                            </includes>
                        </fileset>
                    </testSources>
                    <header>${project.name}</header>
                    <scope>package</scope>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <!-- WEB-INF folder marked as test resource directory to provide possibility 
                to access to spring-dispatcher-servlet.xml and security-context.xml from 
                component tests -->
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
        </testResource>
        <testResource>
            <directory>${project.basedir}/src/test/resources</directory>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
    <finalName>jcommune</finalName>
</build>

<properties>
    <headerBaseDir>${basedir}/../..</headerBaseDir>
</properties>
```

В консоле выбивает следующую ошибку при попытке сборки проекта:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project jcommune-web-view: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.jtalks.jcommune:jcommune-web-view:war:3.4-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at org.jtalks.jcommune:jcommune-web-controller:jar:3.4-SNAPSHOT: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.jtalks.jcommune:jcommune-web-controller:jar:3.4-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.jtalks.jcommune:jcommune-web-controller:pom:3.4-SNAPSHOT from/to opencast-public (http://repository.opencastproject.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/): connect timed out -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы игнорировать это сообщение нужно добавить в секцию plugin management

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
            <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    <pluginExecutions>
                        <pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                                <versionRange>[1.0.0,)</versionRange>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal><!-- YOUR GOAL HERE --></goal>
                                </goals>
                            </pluginExecutionFilter>
                            <action>
                                <ignore />
                            </action>
                        </pluginExecution>
                    </pluginExecutions>
                </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

[Вот](https://www.eclipse.org/m2e/documentation/m2e-execution-not-covered.html) вам ссылка на документацию.

Только проект у вас собирается не поэтому, а по причине недоступности репозитория:

```
Could not transfer artifact org.jtalks.jcommune:jcommune-web-controller:pom:3.4-SNAPSHOT from/to opencast-public (http://repository.opencastproject.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/): connect timed out -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

И, да, без разницы в какой IDE собирать. Можно хоть в командной строке c mvn.